# adding download option for a file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying append some details in to a file and add that for download option,
I am suing javascript and php for this purpose..I  will paste test code to show what Im doing.

on clicking download button, it will fire an ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"php/test.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { totalQuery : test1, },

    success: function(finalEntityList)
    {
        document.location = 'data:Application/octet-stream,' +
        encodeURIComponent(finalEntityList);


    },

});
```

Lets assume test.php has a single line code

```
echo "Test".
```

now I want to add this to a file and make it available for download.I ve used the code

```
 document.location = 'data:Application/octet-stream,' +
        encodeURIComponent(finalEntityList);
```

bt using this when the file gets downloaded in to my hard disk, it shows the extenstion .part and IVe to use the open with option and open it using text file.. Is there any other option to add the download feature?? where I can specify the file extension and file name?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ajax, just use a normal link or `window.location.href =` and set the http headers in your php script to force the browser to save the file.

Comment: I have to use ajax, ive jst pasted a sample code here.. Its a bit more complex than that..